# Possible reasons why Pool map is not using all available resources

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm running the following code

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def loop_f(x, num_loops):
    for i in range(num_loops):
        f(x)
    return 

def f(x):
    result = 0 
    for i in range(x):
        result = result*i
    return result

x = 200000
num_times=200
for i in range(8):
    p = Pool(i +1)
    print(i+1)
    %time res=p.map(f, [x]*num_times)
```

Now when I run this code I see that the performance improvement stops after the 4th  process

```
Timing when using  1  processes
CPU times: user 9.08 ms, sys: 13.4 ms, total: 22.5 ms
Wall time: 1.17 s
Timing when using  2  processes
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 12.1 ms, total: 12.1 ms
Wall time: 598 ms
Timing when using  3  processes
CPU times: user 5.51 ms, sys: 5.6 ms, total: 11.1 ms
Wall time: 467 ms
Timing when using  4  processes
CPU times: user 9.1 ms, sys: 479 µs, total: 9.58 ms
Wall time: 348 ms
Timing when using  5  processes
CPU times: user 4.15 ms, sys: 4.51 ms, total: 8.66 ms
Wall time: 352 ms
Timing when using  6  processes
CPU times: user 6.85 ms, sys: 2.74 ms, total: 9.59 ms
Wall time: 343 ms
Timing when using  7  processes
CPU times: user 2.79 ms, sys: 7.16 ms, total: 9.95 ms
Wall time: 349 ms
Timing when using  8  processes
CPU times: user 9.06 ms, sys: 427 µs, total: 9.49 ms
Wall time: 362 ms
```

But when I check my system, I should have access to at 8 processor cores.

```py
import multiprocessing
import os

print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
print(len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)))
```

```
8
8
```

So what's happening, or possibly happening? How can I maximize my system's performance?

Comment: does it really have 8 physical cpu ?  check the cpu detail.

Comment: You're creating a pool at each iteration of `for i in range(8)`. Shouldn't you just have `p = Pool(8)` followed by `p.map(f, [x]*num_times)` without the `for i in range(8)` loop?

Comment: Correct, this is just to show I"m not getting the improvement in performance w.r.t. to pool size that I was expecting. Though it turns out that I only have 4 cores, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My machine actually only has 4 cores:
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75056/intel-xeon-processor-e3-1270-v3-8m-cache-3-50-ghz.html

```
import multiprocessing
import os

print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
print(len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)))
```

Does not report the number of cores only the number of threads

Answer (score 2):

You should only create a Pool once.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    j = 0
    for i in range(1000000):
        j += i

    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(8) as p:
        print(p.map(f, range(1000)))
```

The above keeps my eight threads busy for a while.

Comment: Joining of pools is required as a matter of best practices and also for executing correctly for all programs.

Answer (score 0):

[multiprocessing.Pool()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process) is used to declare the number of cores you want your process to run on. the different methods of Pool tell how you want to apply the multiprocessing on those processes.

The first problem in your code is, you are initializing the Pool each time with different number of cores. The second is once your pool of workers are done with the processes, you should join them.

I rewrite the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    j = 0
    for i in range(1000000):
        j += i
    return x*x

if __name__=='__main__':
    p=Pool(mp.cpu_count()) #Declaring the Pools with the number of cpus your machine has
    res=p.map_async(f, range(1000))

    p.close() #close the pool
    p.join() #join all the workers
    print(res.get())
```

Comment: Check this now. I actually was concerned about the working of pool, so didn't go through the function properly. This should do your work.

Comment: Still getting AssertionError

Comment: Sorry for that error. Check the code one last time. and also try to follow this practice of Pool().close() and Pool().join() in your further codes.